# Will JQuery override existing inline event handlers?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, jquery

I have a site which is built out of many iframes.
I am working on monitoring user activity - like when user clicks or keydown.

This is only to see if user is idle or not.

For this, I am drilling down to all iframes,its div tags and registering hover and click events.
Meanwhile I dont want to override/break existing inline event handlers which are defined by the application.

Will jquery override exiting eventhandlers? If yes, how can check this to make sure I dont do this?

Here is my usage.

```
$(divElementObj).click( function() {
    alert("div click");
});
```

Comment: Seems like it would be easy to test. http://jsfiddle.net/HZLVy/ Did you try first?

Answer (score 5):

No, jQuery works by using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)/[`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Inline and pre-existing handlers are not overwritten.

[See jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5wae3/1) and the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L116) to show how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use something like `event.stopPropagation();` you should be fine.  `event.stopPropagation();` could cause issues if your existing site is expecting events to bubble.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for it, but you should only do this when you really need to.

[jQuery Override Plugin](https://jqueryoverride.codeplex.com/)

```
$(divElementObj).override('onclick', 'click', function(...));
```