# jQuery prevent children links of row from being propagated when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with classes on some of the rows. All the rows have links and when I click on the actual row I want to execute a function but prevent all of the links from being propagated.

Using `e.stopPropagation()` on my functions is working however one of the links has an `onclick` function and `href=javascript:void(0);` in it so it's just bypassing my `e.stopPropagation` statement and continues to run the procedures of the row-clicking function.

Here's my code:

```
$('[class*=tooltip-properties]').click(function() { // this is the table row
    // do stuff
});
$('[class*=tooltip-properties] a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

And the link causing trouble:

```
<a id="tageditlink25730" title="Edit" onclick="ame_ajax_form_tags(25730, 'LM');return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to stop the inline event handler. If you want to take advantage of jQuery event handling, bind them all with jQuery.

Comment: Can you produce a jsFiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I don't think you understand what `stopPropagation` does. It prevents the event from propagation up the DOM. The `onclick` is for a `<a>`, and your jQuery `.click()` method is for the same `<a>`. How would/should/could `stopPropagation` stop that? It's the same element, so there's no concept of propagation here

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code bypassing your jQuery handlers is the `onclick="... return false;"` attribute.

jQuery will not override inline event handlers, and inline event handlers will be executed *before* any jQuery event handler (see [Will JQuery override existing inline event handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050211/will-jquery-override-existing-inline-event-handlers)). This particular `onclick` handler will prevent the execution of any subsequent handlers, because it returns `false`.

If you have control over the server side code, you can remove the `return false` part in the generated page, or (even better) remove the `onclick` attribute and bind all your handlers using jQuery.

[Edit]

If you can't, one way is to add a child node inside the `a` tag, and bind a click handler on that new node :

```
$('[class*=tooltip-properties] a').each(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    $(this).html( '<span class="wrapper">'+html+'</span>' );
});

$('[class*=tooltip-properties] span.wrapper').click(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that would require hacking Wordpress core :( Is there a way to intercept any javascript calls from the row before they are executed?

Comment: My first suggestion was definitely too dirty. I thought about a new one. See my answer.